# Circular Reference Error in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a function in Excel to calculate default probability. I have a spreadsheet with 3 columns of data. I want to be able to highlight a selection of data, and have the function return a value that's based on the data that I've highlighted .

The function reads in data from a spreadsheet, and then executes an iterative procedure (Newton method) using the data. I'm trying to make the code refer to the first row of a selection of data on the spreadsheet, for the first "i". Then for the second i, I want it to refer to the second row, and so on. So far I've got this:

```
iNumRows = Table.Rows.Count

maturity = Worksheets("KMV-Merton").Range("B2").Value
For i = 1 To iNumRows
    equity(i) = SelectedRange.Cells("1").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value
    debt(i) = SelectedRange.Cells("2").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value
    riskFree(i) = SelectedRange.Cells("3").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value
Next i
```

But this leads to a circular reference error on the spreadsheet. What am I doing wrong?

The full code is as follows, in case the error is somewhere else.

```
Option Explicit
    Private Const mMax = 10000
    Public maturity As Double
    Private equity(1 To mMax) As Double
    Private debt(1 To mMax) As Double
    Private riskFree(1 To mMax) As Double
    Private iptr As Integer
    Public sigmaAssetLast As Double



Function VarunModel(Table As Range, Optional EndCondition As Integer = 0) As Variant
    Dim iNumCols As Integer, iNumRows As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim SelectedRange As Range
    Set SelectedRange = Selection

    iNumCols = Table.Columns.Count
    iNumRows = Table.Rows.Count

    maturity = Worksheets("KMV-Merton").Range("B2").Value
    For i = 1 To iNumRows
        equity(i) = SelectedRange.Cells("1").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value
        debt(i) = SelectedRange.Cells("2").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value
        riskFree(i) = SelectedRange.Cells("3").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value
    Next i

    Dim equityReturn As Variant: ReDim equityReturn(2 To iNumRows)
    Dim sigmaEquity As Double
    Dim asset() As Double: ReDim asset(1 To iNumRows)
    Dim assetReturn As Variant: ReDim assetReturn(2 To iNumRows)
    Dim sigmaAsset As Double, meanAsset As Double
    Dim x(1 To 1) As Double, n As Integer, prec As Double, precFlag As Boolean, maxDev As Double

    For i = 2 To iNumRows: equityReturn(i) = Log(equity(i) / equity(i - 1)): Next i
        sigmaEquity = WorksheetFunction.StDev(equityReturn) * Sqr(260)
        sigmaAsset = sigmaEquity * equity(iNumRows) / (equity(iNumRows) + debt(iNumRows))
    NextItr: sigmaAssetLast = sigmaAsset

    For iptr = 1 To iNumRows
        x(1) = equity(iptr) + debt(iptr)
        n = 1
        prec = 0.00000001
        Call NewtonRaphson(n, prec, x, precFlag, maxDev)
        asset(iptr) = x(1)
    Next iptr

    For i = 2 To iNumRows: assetReturn(i) = Log(asset(i) / asset(i - 1)): Next i

    sigmaAsset = WorksheetFunction.StDev(assetReturn) * Sqr(260)
    meanAsset = WorksheetFunction.Average(assetReturn) * 260
    If (Abs(sigmaAssetLast - sigmaAsset) > prec) Then GoTo NextItr

    Dim disToDef As Double: disToDef = (Log(asset(iNumRows) / debt(iNumRows)) + (meanAsset - sigmaAsset ^ 2 / 2) * maturity) / (sigmaAsset * Sqr(maturity))
    Dim defProb As Double: defProb = WorksheetFunction.NormSDist(-disToDef)

    VarunModel = defProb        
End Function
```

Comment: equity(i) where is this defined?

Comment: sorry, I left out an earlier part of the code where it's defined:

Option Explicit
Private Const mMax = 10000
Public maturity As Double
Private equity(1 To mMax) As Double
Private debt(1 To mMax) As Double
Private riskFree(1 To mMax) As Double
Private iptr As Integer
Public sigmaAssetLast As Double

Comment: Never mind your circular reference. You have no way to force your function to recalculate when you select your range. You must specify the range as an argument to your function.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner at VBA. Isn't "i" defined by Table.Rows.Count,  with Table as Range? How would I specify the range as an argument for my function? Thanks for helping.

Comment: I included two answers because there are two ways to address your problem. 1) You can use a button calling a sub using the `Selection` in the sub; or 2) you can use the function on the worksheet without using `Selection`. Either way you need to remove `Selection` from your function and pass the range as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `Selection` in your function. Using it causes the cell to refer to itself the instant you enter the formula in the worksheet. This is your circular reference.

You need to remove these two lines.

```
Dim SelectedRange As Range
Set SelectedRange = Selection
```

Instead you need to include `SelectedRange` as an argument to your formula.

```
Function VarunModel(ByVal Table As Range, ByVal SelectedRange As Range, Optional ByVal EndCondition As Integer = 0) As Variant
```

Then enter a formula like this in a cell.

```
=VarunModel(A3:C18,A5:C6)
```

The second argument is your "selected" range. The key is that it no longer depends on the selection at all. Instead you tell it explicitly what range to use for the calculation.

This may not be quite the behavior you wanted, but you need to avoid using `Selection` in your function.

Comment: Hey this works perfectly! Thank you so much, I've been stuck on this for days. I really appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use the `Selection` in your code, you need to create a Sub to call your function. You will need to specify the output range in your code.

Create a button on the sheet to run this code:

```
Sub outputVarunValue()
    Dim Table As Range
    Dim OutputCell As Range

    'need range name "TableRange"
    Set Table = Worksheets("KMV-Merton").Range("TableRange")

    'need single cell with range name "OutputCell"
    Set OutputCell = Worksheets("KMV-Merton").Range("OutputCell")

    'use the Selection as an argument
    OutputCell.Value = VarunModel(Table, Selection)

End Sub
```

See my other answer for how to modify the function to accept the Selection as an argument.

Also your function can be declared as Private if you want to avoid having the function used as a formula on a worksheet.

```
Private Function VarunModel(ByVal Table As Range, ByVal SelectedRange As Range, Optional ByVal EndCondition As Integer = 0) As Variant
```